# Jquery Add class only one clicked element

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hi i am going to create small app, using jquery, but I have problem and can't solve it, when i will click  on number box i want to select only one, but now it selects multiple boxes, for example if i click on 36 and then click to 41 it will select both of them, i want to select last one :/ any solution?

```js
$(".checkbox_child").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("clickedcolor")
 })
```

```css
.checkbox_child:not(:first-child){
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.checkbox_child span{
    font-family: firagoregular;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.clickedcolor{
    color: #056304;
    border-color: #056304;
}

.checkbox_main_header p{
    font-family: firagomedium;
    color: #707070;
     opacity: 1;
     font-size: 24px;
}

.checkbox_main_header p{
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
}
.checkbox_child{
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     width: 61px;
     height: 48px;
     background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
     border: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
     border-radius: 10px;
     opacity: 1;
     justify-content: space-around;
     align-items: center;
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="costum_checkbox_main_parent">                     
                      <div class="checkbox_child"><span>36</span></div>
                      <div class="checkbox_child"><span>37</span></div>                  
                      <div class="checkbox_child"><span>38</span></div>
                      <div class="checkbox_child"><span>39</span></div>
                      <div class="checkbox_child"><span>40</span></div>
                      <div class="checkbox_child"><span>41</span></div>
                      <div class="checkbox_child"><span>42</span></div>
                      <div class="checkbox_child"><span>43</span></div>                           
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$(".checkbox_child").click(function() {
  $(".clickedcolor").not($(this)).removeClass("clickedcolor")
  $(this).toggleClass("clickedcolor")
})
```

I've also added a background color to `clickedcolor` just for the visual effect

**Demo**

```js
$(".checkbox_child").click(function() {
  $(".clickedcolor").not($(this)).removeClass("clickedcolor")
  $(this).toggleClass("clickedcolor")
})
```

```css
.checkbox_child:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.checkbox_child span {
  font-family: firagoregular;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.clickedcolor {
  color: #056304;
  background-color:blue!important;
  border-color: #056304;
}

.checkbox_main_header p {
  font-family: firagomedium;
  color: #707070;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.checkbox_main_header p {
  margin: 0 0 18px 0;
}

.checkbox_child {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 61px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="costum_checkbox_main_parent">
  <div class="checkbox_child"><span>36</span></div>
  <div class="checkbox_child"><span>37</span></div>
  <div class="checkbox_child"><span>38</span></div>
  <div class="checkbox_child"><span>39</span></div>
  <div class="checkbox_child"><span>40</span></div>
  <div class="checkbox_child"><span>41</span></div>
  <div class="checkbox_child"><span>42</span></div>
  <div class="checkbox_child"><span>43</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```